# Full Jsp Page is not loading

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am fetching data from database into list in my DAOImpl, then passing this list to JSP using model object.

Page load properly when rowcount from data is as low as 10-12 rows, and if I increase the rows then page does not loads properly

below is my code, which is working properly for low number of rows from database,

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty frList }">
<c:forEach var="fLi" items="${frList }">
<div class='f-detail'>
<div class='f-image'><img src='gui/images/D.jpg'></div>
<div class='opt'>
<c:if test="${fLi.isan}">
<img src='guisdef/images/f441.png' title='This xx xxx'/>
</c:if>
<img src='gui/images/menu.png' class='context-menu' userData='<c:choose><c:when test="${fLi.assd}">${fLi.uhrt},YES,YES,${fLi.FName},${fLi.LName}</c:when><c:otherwise>${fLi.udd},NO,YES,${fLi.FName},${fLi.LName}</c:otherwise></c:choose>'/>
</div>
<div class='nameTag'>
<span class='f-name'> <a href="#/profile">${fLi.FName} ${fLi.LName}</a></span><br />    
<span class='tagLine'>${fLi.tag}</span>
</div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Is there any limitation of size fetching data on JSP

Please suggest.

Regards,
Monica

Comment: If it does not work for 12+ rows, it is definitely not caused by any possible limitation. Probably the rows you are loading when you increase the limit have values that you are not dealing as you think you are.

Comment: Post your error screen please!

Comment: Did you try increasing the <div> length .Probably that helps

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know, is no need to use `<c:when test="${not empty frList }">`. Also I think the `<c:choose>` is useless. So your code should be change into this:

```
<c:forEach var="fLi" items="${frList }">
    <div class='f-detail'>
        <div class='f-image'><img src='gui/images/D.jpg'></div>
        <div class='opt'>
            <c:if test="${fLi.isan}">
               <img src='guisdef/images/f441.png' title='This xx xxx'/>
            </c:if>
           <img src='gui/images/menu.png' class='context-menu' userData='<c:choose><c:when test="${fLi.assd}">${fLi.uhrt},YES,YES,${fLi.FName},${fLi.LName}</c:when><c:otherwise>${fLi.udd},NO,YES,${fLi.FName},${fLi.LName}</c:otherwise></c:choose>'/>
        </div>
        <div class='nameTag'>
            <span class='f-name'> <a href="#/profile">${fLi.FName} ${fLi.LName}</a></span><br />    
            <span class='tagLine'>${fLi.tag}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Nope, that is not the case, with similar code, initially 10-12 div get loaded but if the data is more coming from database, no div get loaded properly,  apostrophe is also not the problem .  I had added userData so that the same data need not be be fetched from database for other fuctional processing.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have access to your data, but I'd be willing to bet one of your last names in the larger set has an apostrophe in it (for example "O'Reilly".   And if any of them have an apostrophe in it, this line is going to cause your HTML to "break":

```
<img src='gui/images/menu.png' class='context-menu' userData='<c:choose><c:when test="${fLi.assd}">${fLi.uhrt},YES,YES,${fLi.FName},${fLi.LName}</c:when><c:otherwise>${fLi.udd},NO,YES,${fLi.FName},${fLi.LName}</c:otherwise></c:choose>'/>
```

Because your data will be prematurely causing the  userData=' to terminate and the stuff after that will be very confusing to the browser.  The easy way to test my theory would be to change that line to:

```
<img src='gui/images/menu.png' class='context-menu'/>
```

And see if you get a lot more data.  If you do, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing your **div** length (eg : **div style="height: 100px;"** ) .

I have faced a similar issue some time back and by increasing the table height that issue got resolved.Just sharing my thought.

Otherwise trying to have a scrollbar in your div